# How to include maven-based project into my non-maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, lucene

I have a non-maven app engine project. I need to include the following library/project into it: https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine. Without using maven at all, how do I make this work? I need step by step details. I have been trying and my code will not even compile. I am using eclipse.

Looking at the `pom.xml` I have figured that I need to download luceneappengine, which I did at http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cluceneappengine. Do I need any other jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, download Maven to be able to build the project. After that, just use "mvn install" to produce the *.jar of luceneappengine (the result will be stored in the "target" folder of the project). However, it will probably need some extra dependencies. To obtain them, use "mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=$TARGET_DIRECTORY". This command will download all the required jars into the specified $TARGET_DIRECTORY.

Comment: One small confusion. Would all of that be equivalent to downloading the jar from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.googlecode.luceneappengine%22%20AND%20a%3A%22luceneappengine%22? That's where I am confused. The `pom.xml` seems to be importing itself. Is that normal? The project in question is at https://code.google.com/p/luceneappengine/, maybe you will understand better than I.

Comment: In Maven Central you can find the releases of the project, while downloading and compiling the project will produce a development version.If you do not intend to develop the "luceneappengine" project, you should use one of the releases from Maven Central. However, you still need to obtain the extra dependencies. You can do it with the command I wrote.