# How to include non-maven Netbeans modules in Maven application?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

I found the opposite version of this question here: [How to include maven-based project into my non-maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435778/how-to-include-maven-based-project-into-my-non-maven-project) but didn't give me any light on the issue.

I know the long road to do this:

1. Mavenize the module in question.
2. Add as a dependency.

But this only works if:

1. You have access to the source of the original module.
2. The project is well structured as this would complicate mavenizitation.

All this seems unnecessary, there should be a better way. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an ant-based module you want to consume in your maven based platform, you will need these artifacts.

- module .jar file
- module's .nbm file

without these, you are out of luck.

If you have them, create a basic pom file, invent the Maven GAV for the module and use mvn install:install-file or mvn deploy:deploy file to upload the pom, jar and nbm file to a place where it can be consumed by the maven build.